# How to make a custom intellij indent?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the follow code in [intellij](/questions/tagged/intellij):

```
class X{
    public void xx(){
        yy();
    }
    private void yy(){
    }
}
```

How to indent private members in diferent ways like this:

```
class X{
    public void xx(){
        yy();
    }
        private void yy(){
        }
}
```

Or, more internal methods more indent:

```
class X{
    public void xx(){
        yy();
    }
        private void yy(){
             zz();
        }
             private void zz(){
             }
}
```

It is possible in default configuration? Exists any plugin to do that?

Comment: Thats really uncommon, to indent methods at different levels. I think it cannot be configured this way.

Answer (score 0):

It is really uncommon, to indent methods at different levels, because it is not possible:

```
class X{
    public void xx(){
        yy();
        zz(); 
    }
        private void yy(){
             zz();
        }
    // Ohh, wait where do I indent this zz()?

         // Here?
             // Or here?   
             private void zz(){
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way to do what you are asking. This is very unusual and have never seen any code written like this. Maybe you would prefer to rearrange your code automatically so private methods are at the bottom or top of your class? This isn't unheard of. You need to use the Rearranger feature.

File->Preferences (or settings)->Code Style->Java->Arrangement tab

See: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/10/arrange-your-code-automatically-with-intellij-idea-12/

Prior to IntelliJ 12 this functionality was provided by a plugin called Rearranger.